# Node Process Won't Exit Unless tskill Is Used

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, express

This is a weird one.

For reference, I am using a MinTTY Git Bash on Win 10. Also, my node is version `v6.11.3`, and my npm is version `3.10.10`. Also, `"express": "^4.16.1"`.

I have never had an issue with express servers suddenly not closing. I have been working with it for a while and only today I started having this issue.

I do my normal `ctrl+c` to close out of a server and to do `npm start` if I did any changes. When this is done, I get an EADDRINUSE error. I googled and googled, finally figuring out that the only way I can kill it is with `tskill <pid>`.

I have tried `taskkill`, `ps`, and basically every other solution that I could use on Git Bash. `tskill` was the only one that worked, as well as using `netstat -a -o -n` to see the list of processes and their PID's.

After doing some research with error handling and signals, I determined that I should add a `process.on('SIG<whatever>', system.exit(0));` line to allow the process to completely exit.

I have tried `SIGINT`, `SIGQUIT`, `SIGKILL`, `SIGUSR1`, `SIGUSR2`, `SIGSTOP`, and `SIGTSTP`. All of them automatically close the process, granted successfully, but without my input, so the server never runs.

Here is my basic app:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var config = require('./config')(process.env.NODE_ENV);
var appPort = process.env.PORT || config.port;

app.listen(appPort, function () {
  console.log('UAction Test Server Running on Port ' + appPort + '!');
});

//process.on('SIGTSTP', console.log('Process Interrupted. Exiting...'), process.exit(0));
```

I really don't know where to go from here. Let me know of any information you need. If I try something and it doesn't work/does work, I will update this main post for anyone else that may have the issue.

What I want to know is either: a) How do I stop this from happening natively? or if not, then b) How do I implement a proper shutdown in my application?

**EDIT**: I tried this with another application I have and it did the same thing.

Comment: This should be tagged as a Windows question. `tskill` doesn't *exist* on other platforms.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy added it, thanks.

Comment: @DarkSwordsman It's possible that you recently added a dependency which is overriding the default SIGINT behavior. Look for code like `process.on('SIG*` in your dependencies. If so, you might need to override that behavior.

Comment: @NeerajSharma I'll check that out, thanks.

Comment: I've had the same issue and found that running ```wmic process where "name like '%node%" get processid,commandline``` helps me find the right nodejs process to kill.  This is from https://superuser.com/questions/1003921/how-to-show-full-command-line-of-all-processes-in-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the issue on Node (even though it ended up not being Node's fault).](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/16103)

The issue ended up being ***MinTTY***. I don't know why, but using CMD instead when installing Git made it work flawlessly. Here are my settings for anyone that has this issue:

- Use Git from Git Bash only
- Use the OpenSSL Library
- Checkout Windows-style, commit Unix-style line endings
- Use Default Console Window (CMD)
- Enable file system caching
- Enable Git Credential Manager
- Disable symbolic links

*(I will mark this as the answer tomorrow, silly StackOverflow)*